# mod_rewrite: change action.something.com to www.something.com/script.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to call a script within a site, co it looks like it is a separte website.
So if the script name is

```
www.something.com/script.php
```

I would like to access it by:

```
action.something.com
```

by setting up .htaccess.

Right now, my .htaccess has this line:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

but this one:

```
RewriteRule ^(action.*)$ script.php [QSA,L]
```

does not work.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The host part is not handled by RewriteRules. You need to use RewriteCond for that

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^action.something.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ script.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, but did not help. Still the last (index.php) rule "fires".

Comment: I had a typo in the first like. Can you check you tried the current version of my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^action.something.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.something.com/script.php [QSA,R=302,L]
```

Change `[R=302]` for `[R=301]` when test work well.